# PHP GAE session sending incorrect information to MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, session, pdo

I have a Google App Engine PHP website with MySQL database attached. The user logs in, enters details into the form, they are saved to the database and then the user can view their own specific entries. This is done by the session, so only entries are shown that match the current username in the session.

I have the following form (I have a session start and queries at the top of the file so all of the php echo comes out correctly for everything):

```
<h2>Sign the Register</h2>
<form action="sign.php" method="post">
<div><textarea name="username" rows="3" cols="60" readonly="true" required="true"> <?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?></textarea></div>
<div><textarea name="firstName" rows="3" cols="60" readonly="true" required="true"><?php echo $firstName;?></textarea></div>
<div><textarea name="surname"  rows="3" cols="60" readonly="true"   required="true"><?php echo $surname;?></textarea></div>
<div><textarea name="course"  rows="3" cols="60" readonly="true" required="true"><?php echo $course;?></textarea></div>
<div><textarea name="subject" rows="3" cols="60" placeholder="Please Enter  Your Subject..." required="true"></textarea></div>
<div><textarea name="level" rows="3" cols="60" readonly="true" required="true" <?php echo $level;?></textarea></div>
<div><textarea name="date" rows="3" cols="60" readonly="true" required="true"><?php date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London"); echo date('Y-d-m');?    </textarea></div>
<div><textarea name="time" rows="3" cols="60" readonly="true" required="true"><?php date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London"); echo date('H:i:s A');? </textarea></div>
<div><input type="submit" value="Sign Register"></div>
</form>
```

Sign.php is:

```
{
 if(array_key_exists('username', $_POST) && array_key_exists('firstName',   $_POST) && array_key_exists('surname', $_POST) && array_key_exists('course',  $_POST) && array_key_exists('subject', $_POST) && array_key_exists('level',  $_POST) && array_key_exists('date', $_POST) && array_key_exists('time', $_POST))
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO register (username, firstName, surname,  course, subject, level, date, time) VALUES (:username, :firstName, :surname,  :course, :subject, :level, :date, :time)');
 $stmt->execute(array(':username' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']),
 ':firstName' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstName']),
 ':surname' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['surname']),
 ':course' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['course']),
 ':subject' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['subject']),
 ':level' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['level']),
 ':date' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['date']),
 ':time' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['time'])));
  $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount(); 
   }
```

If I manually type into MySQL Client:

```
INSERT INTO register (username, firstName, surname, course, subject,   level, date, time) VALUES ('i001','Tom', 'Sm', 'Sociology',   'IntroductionToSociology', 'I','11.05.2015','15.05');
```

Then everything works perfectly. But when I type in (send data) from the form, the data is correctly sent to the database and is there. But not in the correct order, so the correct username isn't being found or even in the 'username' field in the database. Although it should be.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your html is partially broken: `readonly="true required="true"`. missing a `"` after true on the `level` field.

Comment: Thanks just corrected. But the problem is still the same though

Comment: well,s tart doing basic debugging: `var_dump($_POST)`, make sure everything looks ok there.

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner. Where do I put that?

Comment: somewhere in your form handling code, preferably before you start the DB stuff.

Comment: Based on the code above where would you place it?